# The most efficient way to compile application with ns-3 in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, python, swig, jna, ns-3

Currently looking for opportunities to do some ns-3 simulations on Kotlin for the simplicity of the grammar and syntax. 
To achieve this, I can either connect Java to the C++ ns-3 library or to the Python ns-3 binding.

The solutions I can think about are:

1. JNA or JNI
2. SWIG
3. Inter-process communications like TCP and RPC
4. Call Python via script string

I am not sure about how elegant and how complicate the above solutions are. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Your question is broad. Can you be more specific? For example, define a precise problem statement and what you've tried?

Comment: @jpp Thank you for your remind. I realized that stackoverflow is not the best place to ask questions like this. I am asking for advice before doing any implementation rather than asking for help for specific errors. So I will edit the description more specifically, and I will ask for help elsewhere in the meantime.